# A <Router> may have only one child element using react-router-dome. i

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have used every peace of solution that were available in this forum,
installed new dependency... but still getting the error.
*this on is my index file.*
'''

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
import { O_RDWR } from "constants";

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter> <App /> </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker(); '''
```

*and this one is the app file*
'''

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter ,Router,Route,Redirect,Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import Movies from "./components/movies";
    import Customer from  './components/customer';
    import Rental from  './components/rental';
    import NotFound from  './components/notFound';
    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (

         <Router> 
         <main className="container">
     <Route path="/movies" component={Movies} ></Route>
<Route path="/customer" component={Customer}></Route>
        <Route path="/rental" component={Rental}></Route>
        <Route path="/notFount" component={NotFound}></Route>
         </main>></Router>

        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to surround your routes with Router if you already have your App surrounded in your index.js file.

Comment: yes sir ,tried a lot without <Router> , also checked by including <switch>, even simply wrapped it with <dive>, installed new dependencies and also router,but still facing the same behvior.. for more information i,m getting this error in my console *index.js:2178 The above error occurred in the <Router> component:
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:11)*

Comment: Can you provide a CodePen?

Comment: Sory sir, what do you mean? i,m new in development.

Comment: You can add your code here https://codesandbox.io/ for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer of my question...
i have just closed my `<App />` in index.jsx in curly braces like this

```
 ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>{ <App />} </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and it workef for me.i don't know what is logic behind this.